# Generate a WSP package from existing SharePoint 2010 application

Tags: sharepoint-2010, wsp

I have a running SharePoint 2010 application running and I would like to extract the WSP so I can deploy that application in another server.  I have no custom components yet so I'm not yet under Visual Studio.
Is it possible to extract the WSP for the web app from central administration?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to extract the wsp from the CA using the Power shell command.

Please take a look at this

**To take single wsp backup use this**

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm

$file = $farm.Solutions.Item(“JDSU.OneStop.wsp”).SolutionFile

$file.SaveAs(“c:\temp\JDSU.OneStop.wsp”)
```

**To take multiple wsp backup use this powershell command**

```
Start-Transcript "c:\wsp\transcript.txt"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$solutions = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local.Solutions;
foreach ($solution in $solutions) {
$solution.SolutionFile.SaveAs("c:\wsp\" + $solution.Name);
}
Stop-Transcript
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help, the cmdlets have to be run from an administrative account

Comment: Yes Right click on Powershell on select Run as Administrator